# Redux form - how to pass UPDATED props to validation function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a couple fields in my component, most of which are explicitly named. However, I have a button that dynamically adds tickets with an id, for example `ticket1`, `ticket2`, etc. These tickets are stored in an array and available via `this.props`

In my validate function, however, I am not sure how to reference/loop through the list of tickets and run any validations, mainly because I am not sure how to pass down these **updated** field values to the validate function. on page load, it takes the current state of props. however, when I add a ticket, update this.props, and click a submit button, the validate function has a prior version of this.props which I cant seem to update.

Here is mine below

```
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  if (!values.eventTitle){
    console.log('here', values)
    errors.eventTitle = 'Event title required'
  }

  // below, can't do this since I don't know if there tickets in advance

  // loop over tickets array and determine errors
  // ...
  return errors
}

export default validate
```

and then

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    tickets: state.event.get('tickets')
  }
}

const EventFieldsWrapper = reduxForm({
  form: 'EventFields',
  validate,
  onSubmitFail: (errors) => scrollToFirstError(errors),
})(EventFields)

... connect component and redux-form
```

Comment: I should clarify `this.props ` is passed in as 2nd argument, but when i click submit it doesnt deal with updated state. meaning, if i create an input that hasn't been touched, submit doesnt handle any errors until after that field has been touched (and updates props)

Comment: Can you give us a plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem with validate function. Similar I had previous version of store in validate function as second argument. For me solve of this problem was to provide validate prop to Field component of Redux Form. When I provide prop I take a field from store (tickets) and do what I want manipulations with this field.
Example of validation by providing prop to Field component: https://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/