# Using state to determine whether field is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I have username Field which will display error message if the user does not exist in the server after blurred. I can't seem to retrieve the latest props for redux-form after component re-render. I need to do something like:

```
export const asyncLogin = (values, dispatch, props) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const errors = {};
        if (!values.username || _.isEmpty(props.emailVerify)) {
            errors.username = 'Invalid username!';
        }
        resolve(errors);
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you give more details about the issue? It's not clearly what do you want to do.

Comment: Is the problem that you're unable to retrieve redux-form props at all, or that you're unable to retrieve them asynchronously in your promise? Within your promise, do you want the current value of the props, or the value at the time the promise was submitted?

Comment: I am able to retrieve the props but it does not return the new props when the component is re-render (I am using asyncValidate from redux-form). As I am dispatching an action when the field is blurred, in which I need the form to retrieve the new props when the component is re-render. The case is to dispatch an action to verify if the email exist from the server, and then using the new props to display the correct error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok an alternative way is to send api request to validate the username since I can't get the updated props through asyncLogin function. I am not sure if this should be the way since I am using redux-saga middleware to dispatch similar actions to update the store as well, that was why I tried to validate username's field through updated props. A similar question was posted previously  [Redux form - how to pass UPDATED props to validation function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272064/redux-form-how-to-pass-updated-props-to-validation-function). In case anyone facing a similar issue here is how I structure my codes (Any suggestion to how I can improvise or structure my codes will be welcome):

```
// validations/index.js
import * as api from '../services/api';

export const asyncLogin = (values) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        api.appendDomain({username: values.username}).then(email => {
            api.emailVerify({email}).catch(err => {
                const errors = {};
                errors.username = 'Invalid username!';
                resolve(errors);
            });
        }).catch(errors => {
            reject();
        });
    });
};

// components/loginForm.js
const LoginForm = (props) => (
    <div className="auth-form-content">
        <form>
            <Field name="username" 
                component={UsernameField} 
                appendDomain={props.appendDomain} 
                emailVerify={props.emailVerify} 
                action={props.dispatch} 
                usernameInputVerify={true}
                placeholder="Hark, who goes there!" />
            <Field name="password" component={PasswordField} placeholder="What's the password?" />
            <button type="submit" className="waves-effect waves-light btn-large light-blue accent-4" disabled="disabled">Beam me up, Scotty.</button>
        </form>
    </div>
);

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'login',
    asyncBlurFields: ['username'],
    asyncValidate: asyncLogin
})(LoginForm);
```